# Java - Response from button

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've tried many things to get this button `bb` or continue to output "*Hey Buddy*", yet it still does not work. It is displayed yet when i press it nothing happens. The code uses both java swing a awt.

```
package Game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
import java.awt.event.TextListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class base extends java.applet.Applet implements ActionListener, TextListener {

    //Graphics
    //Graphics

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static JButton bb = new JButton("Continue");
    public TextArea ta = new TextArea(30, 140);
    TextArea tb = new TextArea(3, 130);
    public int counter = 0;

    //main class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("---Quest---");
        base ex = new base();
        ex.init();
        f.add("Center", ex);
        f.pack();
        f.show(true);
        bb.addActionListener(ex);
    }

    public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent Continue) {
        bb.addActionListener(this);
        counter++;
        if (Continue.getSource() == bb && counter == 1) {
            tb.append("Hey Buddy");
        }
    }

    //graphics

    public void init() {
        bb.addActionListener(this);
        Panel p;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p = new Panel();
        ta.append("Hey");
        bb.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(bb);
        p.add(ta);
        p.add(tb);
        p.setBackground(Color.blue);
        ta.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        add("Center", p);

        p.setVisible(true);
    }

    //time class
    public static int nap(int time) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

//end of code       
    @Override
    public void textValueChanged(TextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be precise. What is your question? Or is it a coding/debugging request ?

Comment: Debugging. Does it need to be posted elsewhere, sorry i'm new to Stack Over Flow.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, When i do narrow it down into a simpler program its works so i feel as if,something is just not working with the multiple methods..

Comment: Any reason why rye using AWT based components? They were superseded by Swing over 15 years ago

Answer (score 2):

The whole code is buggy.Read the Comments inline.

1.Idk why you are adding actionListener to the button 4 times(Keep one)

2.You have to have to change the `actionPerformed1` to `actionPerfromed` as you are implementing the `ActionListener` and assigning `this` to button's ActionListener

```
public TextArea ta = new TextArea(30, 140);
TextArea tb = new TextArea(3, 130);
public int counter = 0;

//main class

public static void main(String[] args) {

    f.show(true);//show is deprecated use setVisible(true) instead;
    bb.addActionListener(ex);//1
}

public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent Continue) {//have to change the actionPerformed1 to actionPerfromed
    bb.addActionListener(this);//2 What is this assigning inside actionPerformed Need to be removed
    counter++;
    if (Continue.getSource() == bb && counter == 1) {
        tb.append("Hey Buddy");
    }
}

//graphics

public void init() {
    bb.addActionListener(this);//3
    Panel p;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p = new Panel();
    ta.append("Hey");
    bb.addActionListener(this);//4
    p.add(bb);

    p.setVisible(true);//already called a show for JFrame why you want to set Visible of Panel
}
```

Comment: It's an applet, either they need to remove the main method or remove the extends Applet

Comment: You're second point then have the op with two actionPerformed methods, just so you know when they say it won't compile ;)

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention, you're on the right track ;)

Comment: Thanks I got it to work by renaming actionPreformed1 to action preformed. I think that was a typing error on my part. :) I did all of Madhan's changes accept changing f,show to setvisable, I can not get that too work. Can anyone expand on what MadProgrammer was saying... can i not have a main method in a applet?

Comment: @MadProgrammer *Sorry, forget to mention, you're on the right track ;)* I couldn't parse what you were implying

Comment: Over the, the answer is on the right track of the problem, just some minor nitpicks to clean it up ;)